# How to retain dropdown selection within bootstrap's popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, clone, popover, selectedindex

I need to retain user's dropdown selection within bootstrap's popover until it is being cleared. I already made the "selected" attribute can change dynamically based on change of the selection, and made that change replace the HTML select element. I think everything is working (I see it through alert function). Unfortunately not with the "look" of popover, and yes, when I inspect it, it not match with what I get in alert.

Here is my fiddle. Thank You.
http://jsfiddle.net/kDmVq/

```
$(document).on('shown', "#btnPopover", function () {
    $('select#optionDropdown').select2({
        allowClear: true
    }).change('#optionDropdown', function () {
        theID = $(this).val();
        theSelection = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
        $('#selectedID').text(theID);
        $('#selectedText').text(theSelection);
        $('#optionDropdown option').removeAttr("selected");
        $('option[value=' + theID + ']').attr("selected", "selected");
        optionDropdownRet = $('#optionDropdown').html();
    });
    alert($('#optionDropdown').html());
});

$(document).on('hide', "#btnPopover", function () {
    alert(optionDropdownRet);
    $('options#optionDropdown').replaceWith(optionDropdownRet);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with involved writing the popover content back and forth between a hidden div and the popover.  By adding a click event listener to the popover button after the bootstrap popover event, I was able to get to the popover content after it appears and iterate through the form elements...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#pop').popover({ 
        html : true,
        title: 'Popover',
        content: function() {
            html = $('#popover_content').html();
            return html;
        }
    });

    $('#pop').on('click', function (e) {
        initPopover();
    });

});
```

The trick there was to add the click event listener after the popover function. Then, in "initPopover" ...

```
function initPopover() {
    var ishidden = true;
    if($('.popover').hasClass('in')) {
        ishidden = false;
    } else {
        ishidden = true;
    }

    if(ishidden == true) {

        var content = $('.popover-content');
        var html = content.html();

        $('#popover_content').html(html);

        $('#popover_content select').each(function(i){
            var sel = $('.popover-content select').eq(i).val();
            $(this).val(sel);
         });

    } else {

        $('.popover-content select').each(function(i){
            var sel = $('#popover_content select').eq(i).val();
            $(this).val(sel);
        })

        $('#popover_content').empty();  

    }

}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5NQ84/5/